# Sorting list array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, list, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ascending_sort(char *name, char **pName, unsigned int size);

int main(){
   char * names[] = {"Ellin","Alexa","Eliza","Celiza", NULL};
ascending_sort(names[0],names,( sizeof(names)/sizeof(char *)) - 1);
return 0;
}

void ascending_sort(char *name, char **pName, unsigned int size){
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int z;
    int keep;
    char temp;
    /// print out the array
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("str: %s\n", pName[i]);
    }

    ///start sorting...
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        keep = i;
        for(z = i; z < size; z++){
            if(pName[keep]>pName[z]){
               keep = z;
            }
        }
        temp = pName[i];
        pName[i] = pName[keep];
        pName[keep] = temp;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("str: %s\n", pName[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm confused with double pointer(char**).
How can I print out each element of array in function with 'for' loop (so I can easily understand) and sorting it (using 'for' loop)?

## help fix my sorting algorithm, it didnt work

Comment: Have you searched anything on your own?

Comment: To print each element for debugging, you can simply do, e.g. `void ascending_sort (char **pName, int size) { int i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) printf (" %s\n", pName[i]); }`. **Note:** you do not need to pass `char *name`. In reality, since you provide a *sentinel NULL* at the end of `names` you don't even need to pass `size`, e.g. `void ascending_sort (char **pName) { while (*pName) printf (" %s\n", *pName++); }` (**note:** to preserve a pointer to the start of `pName` use a separate pointer to iterate over the names)

Comment: You need to use the strcmp() function to do your comparison. See example below.

Answer (score 0):

A char **, is a pointer to a character pointer. An array name without an index is treated as a pointer to the first element in the array. Your array is of character pointers (pointing to the string literals which are in memory elsewhere). So a pointer to the first element is a pointer to a character pointer, or char **. As shown below, the function parameter can also be specified as char *pnames[], which better reflects that it is an array (of unknown size), of character pointers. A for loop makes the most sense if you pass a size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ascending_sort(char *name,char *pname[]);    
void ascending_sort2(char *name,char **pnames,unsigned int size);    

int main(){
   char *names[] = {"Dnames", "Bnames", "Anames", "Cnames", NULL};
   ascending_sort(names[0],names);
   ascending_sort2(names[0],names,( sizeof(names)/sizeof(char *)) - 1);
   ascending_sort2(names[0],names,(4));
return 0;
}

void ascending_sort(char *name,char *pname[]){
     //print out list of array
     // calculate array size
     unsigned int i = 0;
     char **ptemp = pname;
     while(*ptemp)  {
    i++;
        ptemp++;
     }
     unsigned int size = i;
     printf("------- 1 ----------\n");
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
        printf("str: %s\n", pname[i]);  
     } 
     //start sorting...
}

void ascending_sort2(char *name,char **pnames, unsigned int size){
     //print out list of array
     unsigned int i,z;
     printf("------- 2 ---------\n");
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         printf("str: %s\n", pnames[i]);
     }
     //start bubble sorting...
     for( i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
     {
        for ( z = i; z < (size - 1); z++)
        {    
           if ( strcmp(pnames[z],pnames[z+1]) > 0 )
           {
              // swap the pointers
              char * temp = pnames[z+1];
              pnames[z+1] = pnames[z];
              pnames[z] = temp;
           }
        }
     }

     printf("--- after bubble sort: --------\n");
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         printf("str: %s\n", pnames[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using qsort from stdlib is maybe not what you are looking for. But the sample code below might clear the use of  (char **) pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * ca, const void * cb)
{
    char **a = (char **)ca;
    char **b = (char **)cb;
    return strcmp(*a, *b);
} 

int main()
{
     int numnam, j;
     char *names[] = {"Ellin","Alexa","Eliza","Celiza"};
     numnam = sizeof(names)/sizeof(char *);
     qsort(names, numnam, sizeof(char *), compare);
     for (j = 0 ; j < numnam; j++)
         printf("%s \n", names[j]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

fixed 99.99%... !!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    void sort_name(char **pName, char order[], unsigned int size);

int main()
{ 
    char *names[] = {"Ellin","Alexa","Eliza","4-C", NULL};

    printf("[1] ");
    sort_name(names, "asc", (sizeof(names)/sizeof(char *))-1);

    return 0;
}

void sort_name(char **pName, char order[], unsigned int size){

     unsigned int i;
     unsigned int z;

     ///print out
     printf("Original list:\n\t");
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         (i<size-1) ? printf(" %s,", *(pName+i)) : printf(" %s\n", *(pName+i));
     }

     ///start sorting...
     if (!strcmp(order,"asc")){
            printf("    Ascending sorted list:\n\t");
     for (i=0; i <size; i++){
         for(z=i+1; z<size; z++){
             if(strcmp(*(pName+i),*(pName+z))>0){
                char *temp = *(pName+i);
                *(pName+i) = *(pName+z);
                *(pName+z) = temp;
             }
         }
     }
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
         (i<size-1) ? printf(" %s,", *(pName+i)) : printf(" %s\n", *(pName+i));
         }
     }

     else if (!strcmp(order,"desc")){
            printf("    Descending sorted list:\n\t");
     for (i=0; i <size; i++){
         for(z=i+1; z<size; z++){
             if(strcmp(*(pName+i),*(pName+z))<0){
                char *temp = *(pName+i);
                *(pName+i) = *(pName+z);
                *(pName+z) = temp;
             }
         }

     }
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
         (i<size-1) ? printf(" %s,", *(pName+i)) : printf(" %s\n", *(pName+i));
         }
     }

     else{
        printf(" That doesnt even make sense!");
     }
}
```